# Using || in while loop makes it take too many input values

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

```
public class MetricConversion {
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String masses = "null";
    String volumes = "null";
    String temps = "null";
    String lengths = "null";
    int answer1 = 0;

    String[] options = {"Mass = 1","Temperature = 2","Length = 3","Volume = 4"};
    System.out.println("What would you like to convert?");
    for(int i = 0;i<options.length;i++)
        System.out.println(options[i]);

    while(!input.hasNextInt() || input.nextInt() > options.length)
    {
        String garbage = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("That input is not valid, try again");
    }
    answer1 = input.nextInt();  
    input.nextLine();
```

The problem I am having is that the

```
    while(!input.hasNextInt() || input.nextInt() > options.length)
```

is taking 2 valid inputs instead of 1 in order to make

```
    answer1 = input.nextInt();
```

For example, when entering an invalid input it correctly prints my error message, but when entering a valid input I have to enter it twice in order to break the loop. However if I use the while loop without the || it only takes one value like it's supposed to.

Comment: Your statement `input.nextInt()` in your conditional statement is taking user input.

Comment: You need to change your while loop by a do-while loop and make the necessary condition within your do-while block.

Comment: If the `nextInt() <= options.length` then you already consumed (and discarded) it in the conditional. You need to save that value somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're consuming the value without assigning it to a variable. You can assign it within the loop condition like this:

```
while(!input.hasNextInt() || (answer1 = input.nextInt()) > options.length)
```

Comment: I changed the code to 

`while(!input.hasNextInt() || (proof = input.nextInt()) > options.length)
  {
   String garbage = input.nextLine();
   System.out.println("That input is not valid, try again");
  }
  answer1 = input.nextInt();`

However it still makes me enter 2 values to exit the loop, not sure if I missed something.

Comment: I don't know what `proof` is. If you mean `answer1`, you don't need to repeat the assignment after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are consuming scanner argument in while loop:

```
while(!input.hasNextInt()){
    int argument = input.nextInt();
    if(argument > options.length){
        System.out.println("That input is not valid, try again");
        continue; // get back to the start
    }
    // correctly handle your argument
}
```